# How can I have a software access files on the cloud

Tags: neural-network, network-programming, google-cloud-storage

So I have a small company with plenty of documents and I want to set up an archiving system. I have several employees with different levels of permissions to access the files on the server. This will serve as an archive system plus a management system, as employees can read and write files (depending on the permission) for a certain project, then the admin can prevent access to certain directory (i.e. project).

So after some research I think the best idea is to have a cloud-based NAS in which a user can have locally by giving the correct username and password. Then a software will access these files (which are now local) and can display some data (e.g. project progress, minutes of meetings), or the user can access the files directly.

Does any of this make sense? I mean is that what NAS can actually do and can it be done on the cloud? and can users access the file system (with restrictions) given username and password (much like if it were a network). Is there a better alternative for my purposes?

To the best of my knowledge, I can, instead, create a software that accesses the cloud directly, but how can I get the users to write files and be stored on the cloud? won't that be more complicated to implement? Can I use an RDMS for it? I've used it before but never for files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your use case correctly, all you really want is to have access to different files for different roles within your company, is this correct?

To the best of my knowledge, I believe that Google provide corporate accounts which are quite affordable which should have access control schemes suiting what you need (after all, storing files on scaling storage, with various access controls in an offsite location and with redundancy is partly what the cloud is for).

If not, or if this solution isn't appealing to you and you would prefer to use your NAS, the best way to do this would be to use Google's Backup and Sync application (you can download this by clicking the cog icon on Drive and selecting it). If you install and run this on an admin computer that is always on (and always connected (mounted) with your NAS), you can set a root folder on the NAS as your Drive sync folder. Any files added to this folder will be uploaded to Drive, and any added to Drive will be automatically downloaded. After this you can configure the access control on the NAS using various user accounts and roles, and have each employee mount the store using their own credentials, revealing only the files they have access to.

Comment: Okay, will look into it. Thanks.